# Арифметическая операция

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getWeight(888));
    }

    public static double getWeight(int weightEarth) {
        double P = ((weightEarth / 100) * 17);
        return P;
    }
}
```

Вот что я получаю в результате: 136.0   Как получить 150.96?

Comment: `(((double)weighEarth/100)*17);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как `weightEarth` имеет тип `int`, и 100 также является числом типа `int`, то результат их деления тоже будет `int`.

Т.е. `int/int=int` => `888/100=8`

Чтобы получить отличный от такого результат, необходимо один или оба операнда сначала привести к типу `double` или `float`

Можно так:

```
(((double)weighEarth/100)*17);
```

А можно эдак

```
((weighEarth/100.)*17);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в следующем:

> weightEarth / 100

Нужно исправить на

```
weightEarth / 100.0
```

Т.к. в изначальном варианте происходит деление на *целочисленное*е значение, а во втором на *дробное* число. Как вы помните, результат деления двух целочисленных значений в `java`, является **целочисленным**. Но если числитель и/или знаменатель дробные, то результат будет тоже **дробным**.
Подробнее можно почитать про неявное преобразование типов в [спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Пример: http://ideone.com/iNbd5J

Comment: еще более "понятно", чем мой коммент. Браво

Comment: @rjhdby, я уже ссылку на ideone добавил. Но вообще, вроде понятно должно быть :)

Comment: Впервые вижу, и тем более узнаю о том - что всего лишь нужна была точка. Магия...

Comment: @HelloGoogle, просто `100.` - это дробное число, а `100` - целое. А целые почти во всех языках делятся нацело.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я это понял. Из ответа @rjhdby   :)

Comment: @HelloGoogle, ну тогда принимай его ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него)

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, прошу опубликовать дополнения отдельным ответом, а этот вернуть как было. PS: [Задал вопрос на мете](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/178988). И с чего `100.0` вместо `100.`?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно конечно, но я лишь дополнил вашу идею, своими комментариями.

Comment: потому что 100. менее очевидно чем 100.0 и создает больше вопросов.