# Почему Math.asin возвращает не то число?

Tags: java, геометрия

Я пытался использовать `Math.asin()`, но передавая в него `a/c` я получаю `0.0`. Либо я уже забыл геометрию и тригонометрию, либо что-то не так закодил.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Math.asin(3/5)); //вывод: 0.0; ожидаю: 64 с копейками
}
```

Comment: пробуй `Math.asin(3.0d/5.0d)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Арифметическая операция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625867/%d0%90%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Java при делении целого числа на целое число получается целое число. В данном случае 0.

```
Math.asin(3.0/5)
```